# Why is a text file generated by a SQL job double the size of a manually created one?

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file, text, batch-processing

I have a SQL job running that generates data on a daily basis and amends a text file with this data.

If I copy the data out from the SQL generated text file (currently 24kb) into a new text file, why is it that this new text file is 12kb?

I'm trying to maniplate the file using a batch script and it will only work if I copy out the data from the SQL generated into a new file (the smaller one) which is why I came across it.

Comment: This is very probably due to file encoding. UTF8 vs UTF16 / UCS2.

Comment: Is there a way to check this?

Comment: I use notepad++ as text-editor, which both shows you which encoding is used and allows you to convert it. But to solve your problem you should be looking into your DBMS and find a way to output the data in a specified encoding. As you did not specify your SQL flavor, I can't give you more pointers..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a text file is unexpectedly double in size (i.e. it contains 1000 characters but occupies 2000 bytes on disk), it's usually because it's encoded as some full 2-bytes-per-character unicode represntation rather than ascii, or a unicode scheme that aims to save bytes (like UTF8) by encoding characters using a mix of byte ranges (e.g. UTF8 is 1 to 4 bytes, with the aim that most characters will be 1 byte)

If you want to see more, open both files in a hex editor; it will make instantly clear where all the surplus bytes have gone in the double size file

Comment: Clicked 'Save as' which shows the encoding is unicode.